# How to get the data-mx from .accordion-header BS5

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-accordion

I want to extract a value from `data-mx` I created. When I click the `.accordion-header`. The `max` property will assign to `input#mxlen` to control the max number input. I stuck at sending `data-mx` to the input.

```js
            $('.accordion-header').on('click', function() {
              var tabID = $(this).find('button').data('mxlen');
              $('#mxlen').prop('max', mxlen); //assign max=data-mxlen
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne" data-mx="999">
        Accordion Item #1
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo" data-mx="99">
        Accordion Item #2
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingThree">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree" data-mx="9">
        Accordion Item #3
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="number" name="mxlen" min="0" max="" id="mxlen" />
```

The problem is I cannot transfer the `data-mx` to the `max` property in `input#mxlen`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `var tabID = $(this).find('button').data('mx');` instead of  `var tabID = $(this).find('button').data('mxlen');`

And `$('#mxlen').prop('max', tabID);` instead of `$('#mxlen').prop('max', mxlen);`

```js
$('.accordion-header').on('click', function() {
              var tabID = $(this).find('button').data('mx');
              
              console.log(tabID);
              $('#mxlen').prop('max', tabID); //assign max=data-mxlen
            });
            
$("#mxlen").on("keyup", function () {
    var maxLength = $(this).attr("max");
    if (+$(this).val() > +maxLength) { alert("Please order below " + maxLength + " units.") }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
        <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
                <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne" data-mx="999">
                    Accordion Item #1
                </button>
            </h2>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="accordion-body">
                    <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
                <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo" data-mx="99">
                    Accordion Item #2
                </button>
            </h2>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="accordion-body">
                    <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingThree">
                <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree" data-mx="9">
                    Accordion Item #3
                </button>
            </h2>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="accordion-body">
                    <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<input type="number" name="mxlen" min="0" max="" id="mxlen" />
```

Comment: Well the input must limit the number at most 999 too. Meaning the property `max=99` must be assigned.

Comment: @Wilf every accordion has own max value. So you can check the max value before assigning to see is < 999 or not. `if (+tabID > 999) tabID = 999`

Comment: Is it possible to compare the input length to the one assigned by .prop() right away?

Comment: @Wilf Length? or value? 999 is number not string. So does not have length

Comment: I mean I will check the lenght of `keyup` to `max` assigned by `.prop()`. Can it be done this way?

Comment: @Wilf What do you mean by `lenght of keyup` ?? show me code and say what exactly do you want?

Comment: $("#mxlen").on("keyup",function() {
     var maxLength = $(this).attr("max");//from .prop()
     if(maxLength == $(this).val().length) {
    alert("Please order below " + maxLength +" units.")
     }
   })

Comment: @Wilf The correct way is: ` $("#mxlen").on("keyup", function () {var maxLength = $(this).attr("max");if (+$(this).val() > +maxLength) { alert("Please order below " + maxLength + " units.") }})`  I updated my answer with this code

Comment: Got it now. Thank you very much. https://jsfiddle.net/jezk7d6n/