# LImit max number input from accordion-head and show every n number to div with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I got some successful answers from these links.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/68485231/1620626
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/68489529/1620626

Now I want to put them together. But it seems to have some problems in slicing the numbers and put them in a div. Here's my work:

```js
$('#mx_input,#num_list').hide();
$('.accordion-header').on('click', function() {
  var tabID = $(this).find('button').data('mx');
  $('#mx_input').show();
  $('#mx_input').attr('max', tabID); //assign max=data-mxlen
});

$("#mx_input").on("input", function() {
  $('#num_list').show();
  let $el = $(this);
  var mxlen = $el.attr("max");
  var input = $el.val();
  if (input.length >= mxlen) {
    $('#num_list').append('<li>' + input.slice(0, mxlen) + '</li>');
    $el.val('');
  }
});
```

```css
ul#num_list {
  border: solid 1px red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne" data-mx="999">
        Accordion Item #1
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        body 1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo" data-mx="99">
        Accordion Item #2
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        body 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingThree">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree" data-mx="9">
        Accordion Item #3
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        body 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="number" name="mxlen" min="0" max="" id="mx_input" />
<ul id="num_list"></ul>
```

The problems are:

1. Number is not slice as it expect on criteria `if (input.length >= mxlen) {`
2. As number from (1) not sliced. Then no `append` on destination div.

Here is the link you can easily edit : https://jsfiddle.net/c8jb1hkx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works as expected. In your `HTML` you have max length set as `9`,`99`, `999`. If you want it to be maximum number after that you need to append the list you need to change max length to `1`, `2` and `3` respectively in your `HTML`. Also convert `mxlen` to `number` before comparing.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3mh6ryv2/)

Or update code to compare lengths of both input and data length -

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7mkdjcgr/)

Comment: My code defined `data-mx` as I want number to fill for example `0-9` , `0-99` or `0-999` not limit the input numbers.

Comment: @Wilf, Something like this - https://jsfiddle.net/srbn6dj4/?

Comment: It looks very close. But why I have to type four numbers to trigger the append?

Comment: @Wilf, I have update the answer to include https://jsfiddle.net/7mkdjcgr/

Comment: Perfect! I never known that `number()` has something to do with data type in here.